# questions/tagged strips second tag in 2 tag query for logged OUT user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift+ux will work just fine for me logged in. But if I log out, it will strip the ux tag on the page it serves.

Comment: See: [Multiple tags search broken when searching as anonymous user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243960/multiple-tags-search-broken-when-searching-as-anonymous-user)